# crypt(text,text) call from function fails when function called via JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pgcrypto

Consider the following script:

```plpgsql
create function login_web_user
(
    p_email_address app_user.email_address%type,
    p_password      text
)
returns app_user_session.session_token%type as $$
declare
    v_app_user_id   app_user.id%type;
    v_session_token app_user_session.session_token%type;
begin
    select id
    into   v_app_user_id
    from   current_app_user
    where  email_address = p_email_address
    and    password_digest = crypt(p_password, password_digest);

    if not found then
        raise exception sqlstate 'SM001';
    end if;

    insert into app_user_session
    (
        app_user_id
    )
    values
    (
        v_app_user_id
    )
    returning session_token into v_session_token;

    return v_session_token;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;


create function ws_login_web_user(jsonb) returns json as $$
select json_build_object
(
    'sessionToken',
    login_web_user
    (
        p_email_address := $1->>'emailAddress',
        p_password      := $1->>'password'
    )
)
$$ language sql security definer;

grant execute on function ws_login_web_user(jsonb) to myapp_api;
```

When I execute the following via pgAdmin3 (logged in as `myapp_api`)

```sql
select ws_login_web_user
(
    json_build_object
    (
        'emailAddress', 'foo@bar',
        'password', 'demo'
    )::jsonb
)
```

it runs without error. However, when I execute the exact same stored procedure via JDBC, also logged in as `myapp_api`, I get this:

```
ERROR: function crypt(text, text) does not exist
  Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  Where: PL/pgSQL function login_web_user(character varying,character varying,text) line 7 at SQL statement
SQL function "ws_login_web_user" statement 1
```

I also repeated the JDBC test, this time logged in as `myapp` which owns the above objects. I received the exact same error.

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.4, the 9.4 JDBC drivers and Java 8.

Comment: Make sure the schema (where you created the `pgcrypto` extension) is available in your [`search_path`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH). One way to be sure, is to add it with the `SET configuration_parameter { TO value | = value | FROM CURRENT }` clause in the [`CREATE FUNCTION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createfunction.html) statement.

Comment: Thanks. I found that not setting the `currentSchema` JDBC parameter solved the problem. However, your link to `search_path` made me realise `security definer` is insecure without appending `set search_path = myapp, pg_temp`, which meant I had to prefix all public object access within the function with `public.` (e.g. `public.crypt(...)`). With this done, I retained the `currentSchema` JDBC parameter.

Comment: **SOLUTION** prefix the Crypt function with the schema:  `public.Crypt(...,...)`